# Custom JSON response using Spring Data and Entitiy with @JsonSubTypes in a REST API

Tags: json, spring, spring-data, spring-restcontroller

I'm building a REST API, I'm using Spring Data and having trouble getting a JSON object with some conditions :

I have a `Ressource` Entitiy (`Ressource` with double "s") :

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING,
                     length = 20,
                     name = "TYPE_RESSOURCE")
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
        property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @Type(value = ResHydro.class, name = "RES_H"),
        @Type(value = ResAgro.class, name = "RES_A")
        })
public abstract class Ressource implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String nameRessource;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "farm_id")
    private Farm farm;
    // getters setters....
}
```

The two sub classes are as follow :

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "RES_H")
public class ResHydro extends Ressource {

    private int UnitNumber;
    private boolean moto;
    //....
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "RES_A")
public class ResAgro extends Ressource {

    private String description;
    //.....
}
```

The Farm class related to Ressource class, is as follow :

```
@Entity
public class Farm implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idFarm;
    private String nameFarm;
    private String adresse;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="farm")
    private List<Ressource> ressource;
    //.....
}
```

And a Spring Data Repository :

```
public interface RessourceRepository extends JpaRepository<Ressource, Long>{

    public Collection<Ressource> findAllByFarmIdFarm(Long idFarm);
}
```

And finally a @restController Class with this method :

```
    @Autowired
    RessourceRpository ressourceRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value="/ressources/farm/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public Collection<Ressource> findByFarm(@PathVariable Long id) {
            return ressourceRepository.findByFarm(id);
        }
```

When I access the link `http://localhost:8888/ressources/farm/7` for example, I get a JSON response, with all the Ressource objects WHERE farm_id = 7, like this example :

```
[
{
type: "RES_A",
id: 12,
nameRessource: "t2",
actions: [ ],
description: "uu"
},
{
type: "RES_A",
id: 13,
nameRessource: "t3",
actions: [ ],
description: "pp"
},
{
type: "RES_H",
id: 14,
nameRessource: "ra",
actions: [ ],
UnitNumber: 12,
moto: true
}
]
```

But I need a solution to be able to use a link like this `http://localhost:8888/ressources/farm/7/RES_H` (adding some hint after the farm Id) to get a JSON response with only the objects with the type: "RES_H", and if I use `http://localhost:8888/ressources/farm/7/RES_A` I get only the objects with the type "RES_A" etc...

I really can't figure it out, Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In a JPA 2 query you can do this :

```
select r from Ressource r where r.farm.idFarm= :id and TYPE(r) = :type
```

In your RessourceRepository declare a method

```
@Query("select r from Ressource r where r.farm.idFarm= :id and TYPE(r) = :type")
public Collection<Ressource> findAllByFarmIdFarmAndType(Long   idFarm,Class<>type);
```

In your controller you have to add the discriminator of the subtype as a path variable, so should look like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ressources/farm/{id}/{tdisc}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Collection<Ressource> findByFarm(@PathVariable Long id,@PathVariable String tdisc) {
    Class<?>type=.... somehow find the type that belongs to the discriminator
        return ressourceRepository.findAllByFarmIdFarmAndType(id,type);
    }
```

- because you use @Query in the repository, the name of the find method does not need to follow any convention, so you can name it as you like
- when you call the endpoint,the path parameter {tdisc} should not contain any dots, the endpoint would not be found. When you use the discriminator like 'RES_H' you should have no problems.
- I typed the code here, could not verify it, so typos may be included

Comment: Really great help, thanks a lot. But I still have no clue of how to get the `Class<?>type` by the discriminator value.